# Simple java loop statement with if statements not running correctly?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, counter

I am brushing up on my Java and cannot get this program to work correctly. It is a while counter loop counting up to 100. If the counter is divisible by 3 it will output "On", if the counter is divisible by 7 it will output "Base", if the counter is divisible by 7 and 3 it will output "OnBase", otherwise it will output the number. Right now the program will not even compile and I have no idea what the issue is. Here is my program, any help is appreciated.

```
public class Counter {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 1;

    while(i <= 100)
    {

        if((i % 3) == 0){
            system.out.println("On");
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if((i % 7) == 0){
            system.out.println("Base");
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if((i % (3*7) == 0){
            system.out.println("OnBase");
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        system.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Change `system` to `System`

Comment: `System`, not `system`.  Capitalization is everything

Comment: `OnBase` will need to be checked first, or you will never reach it.

Comment: "Right now the program will not even compile" pay attention to the error the compiler is giving you. What is that error? P.S. though, you can't ask a SO question everytime a program won't compile, you'd never get anything done!

Comment: AJNeufeld I see what you mean regarding "OnBase" would I need to do an if statement stating if i % 3 ==0 && i % 7 ==0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues related to compilation:

1. Change the system to System.
2. The closing parenthesis is missing on line  ----- if ((i % (3 * 7) == 0)) { // added the closing parenthesis
3. Apart from compilation, what you are looking for the logic is also not correct... I will provide some sample code below take a look there too...

> // Sample Code to follow

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 7) == 0))
            System.out.println("OnBase");
        else if ((i % 3) == 0)
            System.out.println("On");
        else if ((i % 7) == 0)
            System.out.println("Base");
        else
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```